# I want to send a HTTP request (get) from my android phone to my mvc asp.net app running on my laptop

Tags: java, android, asp.net-mvc, connection, httprequest

I want to request a list of objects from my mvc asp.net app. I made some requests to several url's and worked fine. The request to my local host app works fine on postman but, for some reason i haven´t figured out, it fails when i try on my phone.

Here´s the request code on android:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
   String url ="http://localhost:44374/Beacon/GetAllBeacons";


    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                String myResponse = response.body().string();
                Log.i(TAG, myResponse);
            }
        }
    });
```

And here's the error message:

```
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:242)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
D/OplusInputMethodUtil: init DEBUG to false, update DEBUG_IME to false
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 44374) from /127.0.0.1 (port 35774) after 9999ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:287)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:192)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:134)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:631)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:71)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
        ... 21 more
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:274)
        ... 31 more
```

I´ve tried with my laptop's IP address, and same error.

I also added network_security_config.xml to my res folder on android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
</base-config>

<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
</domain-config>
```

Comment: Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: Also check whether that port is open first using something like `netcat`

Comment: Is there a firewall between which blocks the request?

Comment: @gtxtreme first of all thanks. Port is open. tried with 127.0.0.1, still can´t connect...

Comment: @Datz already disabled it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you publish your `MVC` web app on `IIS` first then use you PC IP instead of `localhost` in your `URL`

```
String url ="http://localhost:44374/Beacon/GetAllBeacons";
```

and make sure you have Internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: already tried that. Either "ConnectionRefused" or timeout, or some other error.